# SAXBuilder to pass an HTTPS URL

Tags: java, url, build, https, saxparser

Does anyone know how to parse an **https** URL to the SAXBuilder as an argument.

```
URL url = new URL("https:anyURL");
SAXBuilder parser = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = null;
doc = parser.build(url);
```

This code segment works for an **http** URL. But when it comes to **https** URL this gives an java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide the `Key Store` path inorder to call a secure URL:

Example:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\certificates\\xxx.jks");
```